# How to use the editor for git in Atom?

Tags: git, github, atom-editor, git-commit, github-for-windows

I'm using git commit and I already have it configured to Atom so Atom opens a file every time I want to commit a file. The problem is I don't know how to save this file as a commit. If there is no answer to this, how do I get out of using Atom as the editor for my git commit?

Comment: Doing `File -> Save` (or the corresponding shortcut) and closing the editor should work. Doesn't it?

Comment: I have it saved but then this shows up in the terminal: hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file...

Comment: Have you closed the editor too?